# Boolean Method does not return false

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, boolean, return

It compiles, just that it doesn't initialize the `while (choice = false)` so whatever `ans` was entered, it wouldn't show "Invalid input, enter a, b, c: " and reiterate.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            String ans;
            boolean choice;
            System.out.print("Enter a, b, c: ");
            ans = kb.nextLine();
            choice = isValidChoice(ans);
            while (choice = false)
            {
                    System.out.print("Invalid input, enter a, b, c: ");
                    ans = kb.nextLine();
                    choice = isValidChoice(ans);
            }
            if (choice = true)
            {
                    System.out.println("Your input was " + ans);
            }
    }
    public static boolean isValidChoice(String choice)
    {
          if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a")
             || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
            {
                    return true;
            }
          else
            {
                    return false;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you may want `==` instead of `=`. Comparison vs. Assignment. Better yet, you can just use `while (choice)` this checks if true or `while (!choice)` this checks if false.

Comment: One more thing I noticed, but its not the cause of the issue.. You have all three choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a") .. Just to bring to your attention..

Answer (score 1):

**Always use `==` when you need to compare** , which means equality in Java, while `=` means assignment. This is different from some language like PL/SQL.

So when you call `while(choice =false)`, Java only assigns false to variable choice , it does not compare the `choice` with false.

You should use `while(choice==false)` instead, the same in `if (choice == true)`

Check [operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You are using an assignment where you want to use the equals operator. `while(!choice)` or `while(choice==false)`. Same in `if`. In your case you need to differentiate between valid and the actual choice. Maybe it is easier to have the function return more values than a boolean.

And a helpful tip: never ignore warnings of the compiler or the IDE. It will tell you if you do something stupid like assigning in an expression.